# Detecting screen interaction outside of the component in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, lazyvstack

I'm building my own custom list using LazyVStack with swipeable actions thanks to this tutorial: https://prafullkumar77.medium.com/swiftui-how-to-make-custom-swipe-able-cell-727a27abdddd

It isn't half bad as long as you read through it and understand it instead of just copying and pasting. However, much like all the currently available open-source frameworks out there, it is missing a core feature that I don't know if people are just forgetting about or it's just not possible so I thought I'd ask because I can't figure it out.

In a native list in UIKit, if you drag a list item to the semi-open state and have one of the list item actions visible but then interact anywhere else in the list via drag or tap, it will dismiss the currently visible list item action. Dismissing the action is the easy part, it's telling it to dismiss which puzzles me.

I know there are many things apple can do that isn't publicly available but this does seem like something that should theoretically be possible. I'd like to figure this out and make it publicly available as these swipeable actions are a key feature apple seemingly forgot to add before deciding to move towards these lazy stacks.